# Qt connect in constructor not connecting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

A google search gives these as the top three results:

- [Qt: Connect inside constructor - Will slot be invoked before object is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625027/qt-connect-inside-constructor-will-slot-be-invoked-before-object-is-initializ)
- [Qt can I connect signals/slots to self in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641297/qt-can-i-connect-signals-slots-to-self-in-constructor)
- [QT Connect Signal Slot and initialize in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635369/qt-connect-signal-slot-and-initialize-in-constructor)

According to those, it seems like it ought to "just work" like anything else.  But this code doesn't:

```
EditorList::EditorList(..., QWidget* parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    Processing* processing = Processing::getInstance();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(reorderDelete(DataSequence*,ListType,QList<int>)), processing, SLOT(reorderDelete(DataSequence*,ListType,QList<int>)));
    ...
    buttonDelete = new QPushButton(this);
    connect(buttonDelete, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(buttonDeleteClick()));
    ...
}
...
void EditorList::buttonDeleteClick()
{
    ...
    QList<int> locations;
    ...
    emit reorderDelete(mySequence, myListType, locations);    //breakpoint 1 here
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

void Processing::reorderDelete(DataSequence* sequence, ListType listType, QList<int> locations)
{
    if(sequence)    //breakpoint 2 here
    {
        sequence->reorderDelete(listType, locations);
    }
}
```

The reason for this structure, instead of calling `mySequence->reorderDelete` directly, is to have it done in `Processing`'s thread instead of the UI's.  I hope I haven't stripped out too much detail to show the problem; this is a rather large project.

When I click my delete button, I hit `breakpoint 1` (so far, so good), but I don't hit `breakpoint 2`.  My other signals/slots work across threads, but their `connects` are not in constructors.  I want to make this one automatic so that every instance is "just connected" without having to remember to do it.  Can I not do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it.  Leaving up for others to find.

---

[According to this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), my `ListType` enum was blocking the system from making the connection.  It only works with system-known datatypes because emitting a `SIGNAL` actually stores a copy for the `SLOT(s)` to read later.  I knew that, but I thought it was more like a stack frame that could take anything.  Apparently not.

It also works to put a call to `qRegisterMetaType<ListType>("ListType");` somewhere before the `connect`.  (I put it in my main window's constructor.)  This makes the datatype known so that the connection can work anyway.

I'm hitting both breakpoints now.

Comment: That's great that this worked, i just wanted to suggest changes in the code, which will aim creating some pipe for asynchronous purposes. I had same issue while passing complicated data structures through signal emitting, so avoiding it is one of the solution.. + for `qRegisterMetaType<ListType>("ListType");` solution.

Comment: @Guillotine  `...aim creating some pipe for asynchronous purposes` is a bit hard for me to figure out.  You mean like leaving an explicit copy of the object somewhere else instead of sending it through the connection?  I can see that being an advantage in some situations, or I could pass a pointer if I don't need a snapshot of that exact time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used Q_OBJECT macros in your class